# reversing the outer ArrayList in a 2d ArrayList

Tags: java

In java, What would happen if a 2d ArrayList is reversed using `Collections.reverse(someArrayList)`?
 Would only the outside dimension get reversed?

> Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Pixel>> getReversedArrayList(ArrayList<ArrayList<Pixel>> original)
 {
 ArrayList<ArrayList<Pixel>> copy = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Pixel>>(original);
 Collections.reverse(copy);
 return copy;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  Did you try running the code yourself and seeing?

Comment: I did try running it, but could not determine if it was doing what it was supposed to do. I am not good at debugging code.

Comment: What are you using as your debugger? An IDE or a stand alone debugger? Debugging might also be simpler if you filled the 2D arraylist with something you can put original location info (eg a string)

Comment: I am using Eclipse which has so many bells and whistles that it is overwhelming for a beginner. Using string data does sound like a good idea. I know there is a way to test snippets of code in Eclipse, but I can't remember what it is called. I think it might be scrapbook. Do you know of a tool in Eclipse that does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite simply put, `reverse()` does not propagate through the array list beyond one dimension.

Let's say you created an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` (not pixel for simplification's sake) as follows(this is NOT valid java, just an overview):

```
ArrayList //called outer
    ArrayList //called inner-1
        Integer(11)
        Integer(12)
    ArrayList //called inner-2
        Integer(21)
        Integer(22)
```

You then `Collections.reverse()` the outer `ArrayList`.

You will get:

```
ArrayList //called outer
    ArrayList //called inner-2
        Integer(21)
        Integer(22)
    ArrayList //called inner-1
        Integer(11)
        Integer(12)
```

The `reverse()` does not take into account that the `ArrayList` contains `ArrayLists`. It treats them as normal objects and reverses their order without touching their contents. Otherwise, undefined, hard-to-track behavior and all sorts of pigs flying will result.

If you want to flip all inners, use this quick tidbit:

```
for(ArrayList innerList: copy){ //named as per your existing code in the original post
    Collections.reverse(innerList);
}
```

The brackets weren't absolutely necessary in this case.

Comment: Thank you,that is exactly how I wanted it to work. I was trying to create scan lines from a 2d array without changing the value of the original. I could not find any examples to confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the inner elements (instances of `ArrayList<Pixel>`) won't be reversed. If you want to reverse everything recursively deep down the structure, you will have to implement on your own.